# Notification is shown but activeNotifications.size is 0

Tags: android, kotlin

I can see my notification is shown on statusbar from my app.

And I want to check this notification is shown all times programatically.

People says I can use below code.

```
  val mNotificationManager =
            getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        val statusNotifications = mNotificationManager.activeNotifications

        for (statusNotification in statusNotifications) {

            if (statusNotification.id == MyService.NOTIFICATION_ID) {
                // my code part
            }
        }
```

But I check this from MainActivity, and find that `my code part` is not executed.

When I print `statusNotification` in for loop, nothing's printed.

So I print `statusNotifications` it prints:

```
[Landroid.service.notification.StatusBarNotification;@3e95ce5
```

I'm not sure it contains notifications or not.

So I print `statusNotifications.size` and it prints `0`.

But on status bar, I can see my notification.

Even I double check as printing after 5 minutes with Handler.postDelayed(), but also it is 0.

what is the problem here?

And how can I get my active notifications information?

Comment: Are you holding `ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY` permission?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski yes I add that to Manifest but still have same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access notifications, add the `"android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE"` permission to `AndroidManifest.xml`. Request this permission in `MainActivity` using an intent with `Settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS`. Call this intent when needed. Ensure user grants permission before accessing notifications.